# Cumulative count based of values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, count

I am trying to return a `cumulative count` based on other `columns`. For the `df` below I want to return a count using `Outcome` and `Aa,Bb,Cc,Dd`. Specifically, if `X` or `Y` is in Outcome, I want to return the most recent increase in integers in `Aa,Bb,Cc,Dd`. So when `X` or `Y` are listed I want to return that against which integer in `Aa,Bb,Cc,Dd` was the most recent to increase.

I have attempted this using the following:

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'Outcome' : ['','','X','','','X','','Y','','Y'],
    'A' : [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
    'B' : [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],
    'C' : [0,0,0,1,2,3,3,3,3,3],
    'D' : [0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],                          
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

m = pd.get_dummies(
      df.where(df.Outcome.ne(df.Outcome.shift()) & df.Outcome.str.len().astype(bool)
      ), prefix='Count').cumsum()

df = pd.concat([
     m.where(m.ne(m.shift())).fillna('', downcast='infer'), df], axis=1)
```

But it's not quite right.

My Intended Output is:

```
  Outcome  A  B  C  D  A_X  A_Y  B_X  B_Y  C_X  C_Y  D_X  D_Y
0          0  0  0  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1          0  0  0  1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2       X  0  0  0  2    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
3          1  1  1  2    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
4          1  1  2  2    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
5       X  1  1  3  2    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
6          2  1  3  2    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
7       Y  2  1  3  2    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0
8          2  2  3  2    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0
9       Y  2  2  3  2    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    0
```

Comment: You have two somewhat contradictory goals: "return the most recent increase in integers in Aa,Bb,Cc,Dd", and "return that against which integer in Aa,Bb,Cc,Dd was the most recent to increase.". The first is the most recent change (increase) for *each* column. The second applies to which column was the last (most recent) to have a value changed/increased (which may be multiple), and then obtain that value (not the increase itself). Please [edit] your question to clarify what your goal is.

Comment: In your intended output: 1/ why is the column D_Y changed in row 2, when the Outcome is 'X'? and 2/ Why does D_X change from 0 to 1 to 2 when there is nothing in Outcome?

Comment: Sorry @9769953. The output has been amended.

Comment: Thanks, that is clearer. Do check my first comment as well (even if the amended output makes this clearer).

Comment: What happens if a column changes again? Does the `1` in e.g. `D_Y` increase to `2`, and so on (`+1` for every recent change)?

Comment: Don't understand why A_Y row 7 is a 1 and not a 0

Comment: @Boud. The most recent increase happened in Column A. The increase doesn't have to occur on that same row. There could be numerous increases. I just want the most recent one

Comment: I'll update my answer to reflect the most recent change before outcome rows based on clarification from your comments.  I have a few other questions before modifying the code. 
 Does a change in an outcome row count as a change for the next outcome?  What do you want when there is more than one change in the same row?  Will that happen with your data?  Are changes always in increments of one?  Are you comfortable with using numpy along with pandas in your solution?  (It is magnitudes faster with bigger input data).

Comment: The answer is now updated to to determine the most recent increase before the Outcome Column.  I think it produces the outcome you desire, but still have the questions from my previous comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are 2 snippets:

1. As per description, which captures additional increases in A column between 1st and 2nd X
2. As per example, capturing the last increase out of all 4 columns

1) As per description

```
for col in 'ABCD':
    df[col+'_X']=0
    df[col+'_Y']=0

for i1, i2 in zip(df[(df.Outcome=='X') | (df.Outcome=='Y') | (df.index==0)].index, 
                  df[(df.Outcome=='X') | (df.Outcome=='Y') | (df.index==0)].index[1::]):
    for col in 'ABCD':
        if df[col][i2]>df[col][i1]:
            df.loc[i2::,col+'_'+df.Outcome[i2]]=df[col+'_'+df.Outcome[i2]][i2-1]+1
print(df)

  Outcome  A  B  C  D  A_X  A_Y  B_X  B_Y  C_X  C_Y  D_X  D_Y
0          0  0  0  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1          0  0  0  1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2       X  0  0  0  2    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
3          1  1  1  2    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
4          1  1  2  2    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
5       X  1  1  3  2    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0
6          2  1  3  2    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0
7       Y  2  1  3  2    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    0
8          2  2  3  2    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    0
9       Y  2  2  3  2    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    0
```

2) As per example

```
for col in 'ABCD':
    df[col+'_X']=0
    df[col+'_Y']=0

for i1, i2 in zip(df[(df.Outcome=='X') | (df.Outcome=='Y') | (df.index==0)].index, 
                  df[(df.Outcome=='X') | (df.Outcome=='Y') | (df.index==0)].index[1::]):
    change_col = ''
    change_pos = -1
    for col in 'ABCD':
        if df[col][i2]>df[col][i1]:
            found_change_pos = df[df[col]==df[col][i2]-1].tail(1).index
            if found_change_pos > change_pos:
                change_col = col
                change_pos = found_change_pos
    if change_pos > -1:
        df.loc[i2::,change_col+'_'+df.Outcome[i2]]=df[change_col+'_'+df.Outcome[i2]][i2-1]+1
print(df)
  Outcome  A  B  C  D  A_X  A_Y  B_X  B_Y  C_X  C_Y  D_X  D_Y
0          0  0  0  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1          0  0  0  1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2       X  0  0  0  2    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
3          1  1  1  2    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
4          1  1  2  2    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
5       X  1  1  3  2    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
6          2  1  3  2    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
7       Y  2  1  3  2    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0
8          2  2  3  2    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0
9       Y  2  2  3  2    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    0
```

Comment: This is good Sergey. I want to determine the most recent increase before the Outcome Column. So the second example. Is it possible to remove the hard coding of ABCD columns.

Comment: Try replacing the internal loop from ‘for col in “ABCD”’ to ‘for col in df.keys()[1:4]

Comment: Correction, should be: for col in df.keys()[1:5]

Comment: If you want arbitrary number of columns as well, then store the list of columns (excluding Outcome column) before creating _X and _Y columns and use that list for loops

Answer (score 0):

The columns to test for integer increases and the unique values column are set as a variables so that the routine may be easily adapted to input dataframes with other column names.

This routine is relatively fast even with large input dataframes because it uses fast numpy functions within the loop and throughout.

```
# this method assumes that only rows with an increase in one column
# only counts as an increase in value.
# rows with more than one column increasing are ignored.
# it also assumes that integers always increase by
# one.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# designate the integer increase columns
tgt_cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
unique_val_col = 'Outcome'

# put None in empty string positions within array
# of Outcome column values
oc_vals = df[unique_val_col].where(df[unique_val_col] != '', None).values
# find the unique strings in Outcome
uniques = pd.unique(oc_vals[oc_vals != None])

# use pandas diff to locate integer increases in columns
diffs = df[tgt_cols].diff().fillna(0).values.astype(int)

# add the values in each diffs row (this will help later
# to find rows without any column increase or multiple
# increases)
row_sums = np.sum(diffs, axis=1)

# find the row indexes where a single integer increase
# occurred
change_row_idx = np.where(row_sums == 1)[0]

# find the indexes where a single increase did not occur
no_change_idx = np.where((row_sums == 0) | (row_sums > 1))[0]
# remove row 0 from the index if it exists because it is
# not applicable to previous changes
if no_change_idx[0] == 0:
    no_change_idx = no_change_idx[1:]

# locate the indexes of previous rows which had an integer
# increase to carry forward to rows without an integer increase
# (no_change_idx)
fwd_fill_index = \
    [np.searchsorted(change_row_idx, x) - 1 for x in no_change_idx if x > 0]

# write over no change row(s) with data from the last row with an
# integer increase.
# now each row in diffs will have a one marking the last or current change
diffs[no_change_idx] = diffs[change_row_idx][fwd_fill_index]

# make an array to hold the combined output result array
num_rows = diffs.shape[0]
num_cols = diffs.shape[1] * len(uniques)
result_array = np.zeros(num_rows * num_cols) \
    .reshape(diffs.shape[0], diffs.shape[1] * len(uniques)).astype(int)

# determine the pattern for combining the unique value arrays.
# (the example has alternating columns for X and Y results)
concat_pattern = np.array(range(len(tgt_cols) * len(uniques))) % len(uniques)

# loop through the uniques values and do the following each time:
# make an array of zeros the same size as the diffs array.
# find the rows in the diffs array which are located one row up from
# to each unique value location in df.Outcome.
# put those rows into the array of zeros.
for i, u in enumerate(uniques):
    unique_val_ar = np.zeros_like(diffs)
    urows = np.where(oc_vals == u)[0]
    if urows[0] == 0:
        urows = urows[1:]
    # shift unique value index locations by -1
    adj_urows = urows - 1
    unique_val_ar[urows] = diffs[adj_urows]
    # put the columns from the unique_val_ar arrays
    # into the combined array according to the concat pattern
    # (tiled pattern per example)
    result_array[:, np.where(concat_pattern == i)[0]] = unique_val_ar

# find the cummulative sum of the combined array (vertical axis)
result_array_cumsums = np.cumsum(result_array, axis=0)

# make the column names for a new dataframe
# which will contain the result_array_cumsums array
tgt_vals = np.repeat(tgt_cols, len(uniques))
u_vals = np.tile(uniques, len(tgt_cols))
new_cols = ['_'.join(x) for x in list(zip(tgt_vals, u_vals))]

# make the dataframe, using the generated column names
df_results = pd.DataFrame(result_array_cumsums, columns=new_cols)

# join the result dataframe with the original dataframe
df_out = df.join(df_results)

print(df_out)

  Outcome  A  B  C  D  A_X  A_Y  B_X  B_Y  C_X  C_Y  D_X  D_Y
0          0  0  0  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1          0  0  0  1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2       X  0  0  0  2    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
3          1  1  1  2    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
4          1  1  2  2    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
5       X  1  1  3  2    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
6          2  1  3  2    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
7       Y  2  1  3  2    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0
8          2  2  3  2    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0
9       Y  2  2  3  2    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    0
```